# How to move an attribute and its value from one element to another

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, xslt-1.0

I have the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
<Order Weight="1.00">
<Items>
<Item ItemLength="5.00" ItemQty="1">                    
<ItemCharge Description="Chair" Amount="5.50"></ItemCharge>
</Item>
</Items>
</Order>

<Order Weight="2.50">
<Items>
<Item Length="5.00" ItemQty="1">                    
<ItemCharge Description="Chair" Amount="8.50"></ItemCharge>
</Item>
</Items>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

I need the attributes and values in the "Order" element (e.g. Weight="1.00") moved to the "Item" element. The number of "Order" elements and the value in the "Weight" attribute will vary from time to time. The desired result should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Orders>
<Order>
<Items>
<Item ItemLength="5.00" ItemQty="1" Weight="1.00">                    
<ItemCharge Description="Chair" Amount="5.50"></ItemCharge>
</Item>
</Items>
</Order>

<Order>
<Items>
<Item Length="5.00" ItemQty="1" Weight="2.50">
<ItemCharge Description="Chair" Amount="8.50"></ItemCharge>
</Item>
</Items>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

I currently have this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*[not(name() = 'Weight')] | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I greatly appreciate your help!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to think of this as two separate changes, rather than a single "move"

1) Remove the `Weight` attribute for the `Order` element. Or rather, do not copy the `Weight` attribute to the output

```
 <xsl:template match="@Weight" />
```

2) Add a `Weight` attribute to the `Item` element when copying it to the output

```
<xsl:template match="Item">
   <Item Weight="{../../@Weight}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
   </Item>
</xsl:template>
```

Note the use of "Attribute Value Templates" in creating the new attribute.

Also note you should avoid changing the identity template in such transformations. The two templates above, because they use specific names, get a higher priority than the identity template.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@Weight" />

   <xsl:template match="Item">
      <Item Weight="{../../@Weight}">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
      </Item>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: @user3754291Since Tim C was kind enough to answer your question and it made your day, you should consider marking it as the answer. This way he gets the credit and other people that find this question can identify the answer.